# Jquery JSON plugin colliding with slick carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, plugins

I am relatively new to jquery but i need that script to start working properly.

I have an jquery script for reading JSON data from url. It is working by itself but when i try to load data inside slick carousel, carousel stops working. I think that the problem is inside my script. Please help!

My code:

```
(function($){ 
$.fn.scores = function() {
    liveScores();
};

function liveScores() {
    setTimeout(liveScores, 5000);

    var jsonData = "http://url";

    $.getJSON(jsonData, function(rawJsonData){

        var complete =[];

        //var realcatCount = rawJsonData.doc[0].data[0].realcategories.length;

        for (realCat = 0; realCat <= 3; realCat ++) {

            console.log(realCat);

            var basePath = rawJsonData.doc[0].data[0].realcategories[realCat]

            var tournament = basePath.tournaments[0].name;
            var name = basePath.name;
            var matchStatus = basePath.tournaments[0].matches[0].status._id;
            var homeTeam = basePath.tournaments[0].matches[0].teams.home.name;
            var awayTeam = basePath.tournaments[0].matches[0].teams.away.name;
            var time = basePath.tournaments[0].matches[0]._dt.time;
            var date = basePath.tournaments[0].matches[0]._dt.date;
            var homeScore = basePath.tournaments[0].matches[0].result.home;
            var awayScore = basePath.tournaments[0].matches[0].result.away;
            var teamIdHome = basePath.tournaments[0].matches[0].teams.home.uid;
            var teamIdHAway = basePath.tournaments[0].matches[0].teams.away.uid;


            complete.push('<div class="slide-wrapper"><h2>'+tournament+'</h2><h4>'+name+'</h4><div class="score">'+homeScore+ ' vs. '+awayScore+'</div><div class="team home-team"><div class="crest crest-home" style="background:url(http://ls.betradar.com/ls/crest/big/'+teamIdHome+'.png) no-repeat center center;"></div><h3>'+homeTeam+'</h3></div><div class="team away-team"><div class="crest crest-away" style="background:url(http://ls.betradar.com/ls/crest/big/'+teamIdHAway+'.png) no-repeat center center;"></div><h3>'+awayTeam+'</h3></div><div class="overlay"></div><img class="bcg" src="images/bg-live.jpg"></div>');

        }

        console.log(complete);

        $('#results').empty().append(complete);

    });
};
```

})(jQuery);

This is the order i load scripts and plugins at the bottom of the page.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scores.js"></script>
    <script>        
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $().scores();
         });
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/slick.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.slider').slick({
                dots: true,
                arrows: false,
                infinite: true,
                speed: 300,
                slidesToShow: 1,
                adaptiveHeight: true,
                fade: true,
                cssEase: 'linear'
            });
        });
    </script>
```

First i load carousels item (JSON data) and then the slick carousel itself.

And the slick carousel works just fine until i put data from my plugin into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code provided is not very good,

- for instance you don't know if there are 3 realcats (0,1,2)
- don't use json as a variable name, json is a notation, not an good variable name

  $.getJSON(jsonData, function(rawJsonData){
              var complete =[];
              var realcatCount = rawJsonData.doc[0].data[0].realcategories.length;

  ```
          for (realCat = 0; realCat <= (realcatCount  -1); realcatCount ++) {
              console.log(realCat);
              var basePath = json.doc[0].data[0].realcategories[realCat]
  ```

  ...

The rest of your code seems ok, but not really good.
Try to walk the json path as less as needed. 
    this would be:
    var match = basePath.tournaments[0].matches[0];
    var matchStatus = match .status._id;
    var homeTeam = match .teams.home.name;

What you need to do is make sure your html is there BEFORE you bind it. so first generate the carrousel items, and then perform the .slick() function

This way you would get:
// Your existingt code..
        $('#results').empty().append(complete);

// AND then slick it..  Delete this code from the seperate code block in your html and move it to here..

```
    $('.slider').slick({
        dots: true,
        arrows: false,
        infinite: true,
        speed: 300,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        adaptiveHeight: true,
        fade: true,
        cssEase: 'linear'
    });
```

Your problem is that .slick is called BEFORE the html is there (it is derived from a web url)

- first create the html, and append it
- then do .slick

The resulting (working) code:
https://jsfiddle.net/aeuuymuy/12/

Comment: Thank you, i have corrected that issues, but my main problem is still there. I can't get plugin to work with slick carousel or with any other plugin...

Comment: I have edited my question, so that plugin order load is visible.

Comment: Sorry, or i don't understand correctly or it doesn't work. The structure of slick slider looks right, the css and everything is ok, it simply like slick (or any other plugins) doesn't work with my plugin. Is my plugin syntax ok?

Comment: I think you don't understand it. Slick is functioning well, and your code also. This is a timing issue. Where you first tell slick to do it's thing but nothing is there yet..

Please correct your code by moving the .slick() code to the .js file just after you append it to the DOM.

Comment: Thank you very much, now it kinda works... Now the issue is, when juery refreshes it throws an error and i loose slick slider again 'Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined' referring to: <script>  
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $().scores();
    });
  </script>

Comment: It is not the error, it happens without error also. At first i have a slider but on refresh i loose it

Comment: What do you mean with "loose it" and what do you mean with "refresh" ?

Comment: Jquery has setTimeout to get live JSON data. And when it 'refreshes' data, it's like there is no slick carousel plugin again.

Comment: I am making a fiddl example: can you pass your url where I can get the data? (then I try to make it working)

Comment: Great! It works! Any ideas maybe how should i update plugin so that it stays on the same slide (dot) after refresh? Now it throws you on the first one after a timeout?

Comment: That, I don't know. Please mark the answer as best answer.

I would personally add one check: if the incoming data is exactly the same as the already existing data, jyst do nothing (dont refresh)